# Internal API server error on calling to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

Tags: linkedin-api

We have an error in authentication requests.
When our application was receive `code` and try to exchange them with **access token** by calling to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken, the LinkedIn API return: `errorCode=0, message=Internal API server error, requestId=KIEGT2ADK7, status=500, timestamp=1518791169197`

Please, help us with this issue. This erroneous response is stable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly add this Header
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I don't know, because of I use Spring Framework for integrations with social media. This issue exists only for specific user, for others auth works as expected. Therefore, I attached an requestId so that LinkedIn employees could understand the reason.